# What determines the range of values in getView()'s position parameter?

Tags: android

I'm getting a crash in my adapter's getView() routine because it's being called with a position value of 6 and my datasource only has 6 items in it.  So I assumed that the position parameter should be in a range of [0]-[5]?  What determines the range of values in getView()'s position parameter?

**Details:**

the XML ...

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:cacheColorHint="@color/colGrey"
  android:background="@color/colGrey"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
  android:choiceMode="none"/>
```

...In MyListActivity, which is a ListActivity . . .

```
public static ListView lv;   // my ListView in the code
```

... during *onCreate()* . . .

```
   setContentView(R.layout.mylist);
   lv = getListView();
```

create the adapter and bind it . . .

```
mylistadapter = new MyListAdapter(MyListActivity.this);
setListAdapter(mylistadapter);   // bind the adapter
```

...the data source is an ArrayList called listItems. during the course of running the program its size varies and it may have been 15 earlier in program execution . . .

```
public static ArrayList<String>listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
```

... in my adapter, which is a BaseAdapter, my ovveride of getCount() looks like this . . .

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}
```

... when I call getCount() in getView() it returns 6, which is the number of items in the data source, but if I call lv.getCount() it returns 15. (any idea where this 15 is coming from?)   Could that be why the adapter is calling getView with index too big?

Comment: `lv.getView()` ListView doesn't have a `getView()` method.  What are you referring to here?

Comment: ... sorry lv.getCount (I've fixed it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I assumed that the position parameter should be in a range of [0]-[5]?

Yes.

> What determines the range of values in getView()'s position parameter?

It will range from 0 to `getCount()`-1, where `getCount()` is implemented on the `Adapter`.

> during the course of running the program its size varies and it may have been 15 earlier in program execution

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter` if you change the data, including changing the number of rows.

Comment: I am calling notifyDataSetChanged().   But I'm calling it inside of a runnable (which I thought was the canonically correct way to do it).   Is it possible that that thread isn't being executed until after it's too late, i.e, after getView() has already been called 6 times?   If I'm sitting in a loop updating my dataset (listItems, above) how do I tell the adapter not to call getView() until I'm done?

Comment: @user316117: "But I'm calling it inside of a runnable (which I thought was the canonically correct way to do it)." -- not necessarily. It needs to be called on the main application thread. "Is it possible that that thread isn't being executed until after it's too late" -- what thread? "If I'm sitting in a loop updating my dataset (listItems, above) how do I tell the adapter not to call getView() until I'm done?" -- you have to make all your changes on the main application thread. Fetch the data in the background, but **only** change what the `BaseAdapter` has on the main application thread.

Comment: @user316117: Yes. So, on the main application thread, you change what your `BaseAdapter` holds onto in terms of its model data, then immediately call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Android, later on the main application thread, will call `getCount()` to get the revised count, at which point the `ListView` and your `BaseAdapter` should be back in sync.

Comment: In this SO article [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example) they suggest a runnable of **runOnUiThread** What's the advantage of doing it that way?

Comment: @user316117: `runOnUiThread()` runs the supplied `Runnable` on the main application thread. Using `runOnUiThread()` from a background thread is a perfectly fine way to get your `BaseAdapter`-updating logic, including the `notifyDataSetChanged()` call, to occur on the main application thread.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered because it clearly has **something** to do with how I'm calling _notifyDataSetChanged()_.  (I'm only doing it from 1 place where I do an _add()_ to my dataset then call _notifyDataSetChanged()_) When I embed logging in my code I can see that the crashes are happening when getView() is executed before _notifyDataSetChanged()_ gets executed.